# Thrust Complex Inner Product Run on GPU Slower Than STL Implementation on CPU

Tags: c++, stl, cuda, gpu, thrust

I've got the following two implementations of computing a complex inner product, one using STL libraries running on the CPU and one using Thrust running on the GPU:

**CPU Implementation**

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <complex>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int vec_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    std::vector< std::complex<float> > host_x( vec_size );
    std::generate(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), std::rand);

    std::vector< std::complex<float> > host_y( vec_size );
    std::generate(host_y.begin(), host_y.end(), std::rand);

    std::complex<float> z = std::inner_product(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), host_y.begin(), std::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );

    return 0;
}
```

**GPU Implementation**

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int vec_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_x( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), rand);

    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_y( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_y.begin(), host_y.end(), rand);

    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_x = host_x;
    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_y = host_y;

    thrust::complex<float> z = thrust::inner_product(device_x.begin(), device_x.end(), device_y.begin(), thrust::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the CPU implementation using g++ and the GPU implementation using mvcc. Both have -O3 optimizations on. I run both implementations with 3,000,000 elements in the vector and get the following timing results:

CPU:
real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.100s
sys 0m0.048s

GPU:
real    0m0.284s
user    0m0.190s
sys 0m0.083s

I'm using the following pieces of software:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Sep__5_10:17:14_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

Along with the latest version of Thrust from the GitHub repo.

My CPU is a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and my GPU is a NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB.

**Question:**
I'm new to the use of Thrust, but shouldn't my GPU implementation be significantly faster than my CPU implementation? I realize that there are memory transaction costs with GPUs, but I guess I'm trying to figure out if I'm using Thrust correctly to execute the inner product on the GPU since the timing results are unexpectedly reversed in my opinion.

**EDIT:**
Per everyone's suggestions I made the number of iterations configurable and changed the granularity of the timing as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int vec_size = atoi(argv[1]);
    int iterations = atoi(argv[2]);

    float milliseconds = 0;

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_x( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), rand);

    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_y( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_y.begin(), host_y.end(), rand);

    printf("vector size = %lu bytes\n", vec_size * sizeof(thrust::complex<float>)); 

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_x = host_x;
    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_y = host_y;
    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("copy (device)\t\t%f ms\n", milliseconds);

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        thrust::inner_product(thrust::cuda::par, device_x.begin(), device_x.end(), device_y.begin(), thrust::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );
    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("inner_product (device)\t%f ms\n", milliseconds/iterations); 

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        thrust::inner_product(thrust::host, host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), host_y.begin(), thrust::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );
    }

    cudaEventRecord(stop);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("inner_product (host)\t%f ms\n", milliseconds/iterations);   

    return 0;
}
```

On a Tegra K1 I got the following:

```
$ nvcc complex_inner_product.cu -O3 -arch=sm_32 -o cip
$ ./cip 3100000 1000
vector size = 24800000 bytes
copy (device)       45.741653 ms
inner_product (device)  10.595121 ms
inner_product (host)    1.807912 ms
```

On an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.4 GHz and GeForce 320M I got the following results:

```
$ nvcc complex_inner_product.cu -O3 -arch=sm_12 -o cip
$ ./cip 3100000 1000
vector size = 24800000 bytes
copy (device)       227.765213 ms
inner_product (device)  42.180416 ms
inner_product (host)    0.000018 ms
```

On an Intel Core i5 3.3 GHz and GeForce GT 755M:

```
$ nvcc complex_inner_product.cu -O3 -arch=sm_30 -o cip
$ ./cip 3100000 1000
vector size = 24800000 bytes
copy (device)       22.930016 ms
inner_product (device)  6.249663 ms
inner_product (host)    0.000003 ms
```

So no matter what compute capability or hardware I use, the host processor is at least 10x faster than the GPU. Any ideas?

Comment: Your test is too short. Try running this in a loop (say, 1,000 times), and measure. You may be witnessing initial setup times that disappear when you're testing a longer process.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things to consider with your benchmarking approach.   I'm not arguing whether your results are valid; that's a matter of opinion, based on what you consider important.  But some things to consider are:

1. CUDA startup time is included in your measurement.
2. Data transfer times are included in your measurement.
3. You are doing only one measurement pass.
4. You are using a very low end GPU.
5. Your choice of function to test is not very compute-intensive (a few flops per float quantity).

If you *just* time the computation portion, I expect you'll find the GPU looking a little better.  Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t489.cu
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <complex>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    timeval tv1, tv2;
    int vec_size = atoi(argv[1]);

    std::vector< std::complex<float> > cpu_x( vec_size );
    std::generate(cpu_x.begin(), cpu_x.end(), std::rand);

    std::vector< std::complex<float> > cpu_y( vec_size );
    std::generate(cpu_y.begin(), cpu_y.end(), std::rand);

    gettimeofday(&tv1, 0);
    std::complex<float> cpu_z = std::inner_product(cpu_x.begin(), cpu_x.end(), cpu_y.begin(), std::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );
    gettimeofday(&tv2, 0);
    std::cout <<"CPU result: " << cpu_z.real() << "," << cpu_z.imag() << std::endl;
    unsigned t2 = (tv2.tv_sec*1000000) + tv2.tv_usec;
    unsigned t1 = (tv1.tv_sec*1000000) + tv1.tv_usec;
    float et = (t2-t1)/(float) 1000;
    std::cout << "CPU elapsed time: " << et << "ms" << std::endl;
    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_x( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_x.begin(), host_x.end(), rand);

    thrust::host_vector< thrust::complex<float> > host_y( vec_size );
    thrust::generate(host_y.begin(), host_y.end(), rand);

    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_x = host_x;
    thrust::device_vector< thrust::complex<float> > device_y = host_y;

    gettimeofday(&tv1, 0);
    thrust::complex<float> z = thrust::inner_product(device_x.begin(), device_x.end(), device_y.begin(), thrust::complex<float>(0.0f,0.0f) );
    gettimeofday(&tv2, 0);
    std::cout <<"GPU result: " << z.real() << "," << z.imag() << std::endl;
    t2 = (tv2.tv_sec*1000000) + tv2.tv_usec;
    t1 = (tv1.tv_sec*1000000) + tv1.tv_usec;
    et = (t2-t1)/(float) 1000;
    std::cout << "GPU elapsed time: " << et << "ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -O3 -o t489 t489.cu
$ ./t489 3000000
CPU result: 3.45238e+24,0
CPU elapsed time: 19.294ms
GPU result: 3.46041e+24,0
GPU elapsed time: 3.426ms
$
```

This was run with a Quadro5000 GPU (considerably more powerful than your GT320M), RHEL 5.5, CUDA 6.5RC, Thrust 1.8 (master branch)

So which numbers matter?  That's up to you.  If you were just intending to do this single inner product on the GPU, and no other computations or any activity on the GPU, it would be senseless to use the GPU.  But in the context of a larger problem, where inner product is just one of the pieces, the GPU may well be faster than the CPU.

(The results don't match because the program is generating differing starting values in each case.)

Comment: See edit with more representative benchmark results.

Comment: certainly when you see a host timing of 3 *nanoseconds*, you should start to question your timing method.  When you saw in your last two cases that the host was 2 *million* times faster than the device, did this not cause you to pause for thought?  "Hmmm, that can't be right."  [Here](http://pastebin.com/ysDKC1ZB) are my results from running your current code.  Did you run my code?